# Why does cv2.fitEllipse considers contours as side of ellipse?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ellipse

I am encountering a weird problem with cv2.fitEllipse. When I try to get this ellipse of this form, 
[image: form]

that can be defined (sorry for the long list of definition) as:

```
import numpy as np
test=np.zeros((400,1000))
test[241, 113]=1
test[241, 114]=1
test[242, 112]=1
test[242, 113]=1
test[242, 114]=1
test[242, 115]=1
test[242, 116]=1
test[242, 118]=1
test[242, 119]=1
test[242, 120]=1
test[242, 121]=1
test[243, 111]=1
test[243, 112]=1
test[243, 113]=1
test[243, 114]=1
test[243, 115]=1
test[243, 116]=1
test[243, 117]=1
test[243, 118]=1
test[243, 119]=1
test[243, 120]=1
test[243, 121]=1
test[244, 110]=1
test[244, 111]=1
test[244, 112]=1
test[244, 113]=1
test[244, 114]=1
test[244, 115]=1
test[244, 116]=1
test[244, 117]=1
test[244, 118]=1
test[244, 119]=1
test[244, 120]=1
test[245, 109]=1
test[245, 110]=1
test[245, 111]=1
test[245, 112]=1
test[245, 113]=1
test[245, 114]=1
test[245, 115]=1
test[245, 116]=1
test[245, 117]=1
test[245, 118]=1
test[245, 119]=1
test[245, 120]=1
test[246, 109]=1
test[246, 110]=1
test[246, 111]=1
test[246, 112]=1
test[246, 113]=1
test[246, 114]=1
test[246, 115]=1
test[246, 116]=1
test[246, 117]=1
test[246, 118]=1
test[246, 119]=1
test[247, 109]=1
test[247, 110]=1
test[247, 111]=1
test[247, 112]=1
test[247, 113]=1
test[247, 114]=1
test[247, 115]=1
test[247, 116]=1
test[247, 117]=1
test[247, 118]=1
test[247, 119]=1
test[248, 108]=1
test[248, 109]=1
test[248, 110]=1
test[248, 111]=1
test[248, 112]=1
test[248, 113]=1
test[248, 114]=1
test[248, 115]=1
test[248, 116]=1
test[248, 117]=1
test[248, 118]=1
test[248, 119]=1
test[249, 109]=1
test[249, 110]=1
test[249, 111]=1
test[249, 112]=1
test[249, 113]=1
test[249, 114]=1
test[249, 115]=1
test[249, 116]=1
test[249, 117]=1
test[249, 118]=1
test[249, 119]=1
test[250, 109]=1
test[250, 110]=1
test[250, 111]=1
test[250, 112]=1
test[250, 113]=1
test[250, 114]=1
test[250, 115]=1
test[250, 116]=1
test[250, 117]=1
test[250, 118]=1
test[250, 119]=1
test[250, 120]=1
test[251, 109]=1
test[251, 110]=1
test[251, 111]=1
test[251, 112]=1
test[251, 113]=1
test[251, 114]=1
test[251, 115]=1
test[251, 116]=1
test[251, 117]=1
test[251, 118]=1
test[251, 119]=1
test[251, 120]=1
test[252, 109]=1
test[252, 110]=1
test[252, 111]=1
test[252, 112]=1
test[252, 113]=1
test[252, 114]=1
test[252, 115]=1
test[252, 116]=1
test[252, 117]=1
test[252, 118]=1
test[252, 119]=1
test[252, 120]=1
test[252, 121]=1
test[253, 109]=1
test[253, 112]=1
test[253, 113]=1
test[253, 114]=1
test[253, 115]=1
test[253, 116]=1
test[253, 117]=1
test[253, 118]=1
test[253, 119]=1
test[253, 120]=1
test[253, 121]=1
test[254, 112]=1
test[254, 113]=1
test[254, 114]=1
test[254, 115]=1
test[254, 116]=1
test[254, 117]=1
test[254, 118]=1
test[254, 119]=1
test[254, 120]=1
test[254, 121]=1
test[255, 110]=1
test[255, 112]=1
test[255, 113]=1
test[255, 114]=1
test[255, 115]=1
test[255, 116]=1
test[255, 117]=1
test[255, 118]=1
test[255, 119]=1
test[255, 120]=1
test[255, 121]=1
test[255, 122]=1
test[256, 108]=1
test[256, 110]=1
test[256, 111]=1
test[256, 112]=1
test[256, 113]=1
test[256, 114]=1
test[256, 115]=1
test[256, 116]=1
test[256, 117]=1
test[256, 118]=1
test[256, 119]=1
test[256, 120]=1
test[256, 121]=1
test[256, 122]=1
test[256, 123]=1
test[257, 106]=1
test[257, 107]=1
test[257, 108]=1
test[257, 109]=1
test[257, 110]=1
test[257, 111]=1
test[257, 112]=1
test[257, 113]=1
test[257, 114]=1
test[257, 115]=1
test[257, 116]=1
test[257, 117]=1
test[257, 118]=1
test[257, 119]=1
test[257, 120]=1
test[257, 121]=1
test[257, 122]=1
test[257, 123]=1
test[257, 124]=1
test[258, 103]=1
test[258, 104]=1
test[258, 105]=1
test[258, 106]=1
test[258, 107]=1
test[258, 108]=1
test[258, 109]=1
test[258, 110]=1
test[258, 111]=1
test[258, 112]=1
test[258, 113]=1
test[258, 114]=1
test[258, 115]=1
test[258, 116]=1
test[258, 117]=1
test[258, 118]=1
test[258, 119]=1
test[258, 120]=1
test[258, 121]=1
test[258, 122]=1
test[258, 123]=1
test[258, 124]=1
test[259, 103]=1
test[259, 104]=1
test[259, 105]=1
test[259, 106]=1
test[259, 107]=1
test[259, 108]=1
test[259, 109]=1
test[259, 110]=1
test[259, 111]=1
test[259, 112]=1
test[259, 113]=1
test[259, 114]=1
test[259, 115]=1
test[259, 116]=1
test[259, 117]=1
test[259, 118]=1
test[259, 119]=1
test[259, 120]=1
test[259, 121]=1
test[259, 122]=1
test[259, 123]=1
test[259, 124]=1
test[260, 106]=1
test[260, 107]=1
test[260, 108]=1
test[260, 109]=1
test[260, 110]=1
test[260, 111]=1
test[260, 112]=1
test[260, 113]=1
test[260, 114]=1
test[260, 115]=1
test[260, 116]=1
test[260, 117]=1
test[260, 118]=1
test[260, 119]=1
test[260, 120]=1
test[260, 121]=1
test[260, 122]=1
test[260, 123]=1
test[260, 124]=1
test[261, 107]=1
test[261, 110]=1
test[261, 111]=1
test[261, 112]=1
test[261, 113]=1
test[261, 114]=1
test[261, 115]=1
test[261, 116]=1
test[261, 117]=1
test[261, 118]=1
test[261, 119]=1
test[261, 120]=1
test[261, 121]=1
test[261, 122]=1
test[261, 123]=1
test[261, 124]=1
test[261, 125]=1
test[262, 115]=1
test[262, 116]=1
test[262, 117]=1
test[262, 118]=1
test[262, 119]=1
test[262, 120]=1
test[262, 121]=1
test[262, 122]=1
test[262, 123]=1
test[262, 124]=1
test[262, 125]=1
test[262, 126]=1
test[262, 127]=1
test[262, 128]=1
test[263, 116]=1
test[263, 117]=1
test[263, 118]=1
test[263, 119]=1
test[263, 120]=1
test[263, 121]=1
test[263, 122]=1
test[263, 123]=1
test[263, 127]=1
test[263, 128]=1
test[263, 129]=1
test[263, 130]=1
test[263, 131]=1
test[263, 132]=1
test[263, 133]=1
test[263, 134]=1
test[263, 135]=1
test[264, 117]=1
test[264, 118]=1
test[264, 119]=1
test[264, 120]=1
test[264, 121]=1
test[264, 122]=1
test[264, 123]=1
test[264, 127]=1
test[264, 128]=1
test[264, 129]=1
test[264, 130]=1
test[264, 131]=1
test[264, 132]=1
test[264, 133]=1
test[264, 134]=1
test[264, 135]=1
test[264, 136]=1
test[264, 138]=1
test[264, 139]=1
test[265, 118]=1
test[265, 119]=1
test[265, 120]=1
test[265, 121]=1
test[265, 122]=1
test[265, 123]=1
test[265, 131]=1
test[265, 134]=1
test[265, 135]=1
test[265, 136]=1
test[265, 137]=1
test[265, 138]=1
test[265, 139]=1
test[265, 140]=1
test[265, 141]=1
test[265, 142]=1
test[265, 143]=1
test[266, 120]=1
test[266, 121]=1
test[266, 122]=1
test[266, 135]=1
test[266, 136]=1
test[266, 137]=1
test[266, 138]=1
test[266, 139]=1
test[266, 140]=1
test[266, 141]=1
test[266, 142]=1
test[266, 143]=1
test[266, 144]=1
test[266, 145]=1
test[267, 121]=1
test[267, 122]=1
test[267, 142]=1
test[267, 143]=1
test[267, 144]=1
test[267, 145]=1
test[267, 146]=1
test[267, 147]=1
test[267, 148]=1
test[267, 149]=1
test[267, 150]=1
test[267, 151]=1
test[268, 147]=1
test[268, 148]=1
test[268, 149]=1
test[268, 150]=1
test[268, 151]=1
test[268, 152]=1
test[268, 153]=1
test[268, 154]=1
test[268, 155]=1
test[268, 156]=1
test[268, 157]=1
test[269, 149]=1
test[269, 151]=1
test[269, 152]=1
test[269, 153]=1
test[269, 154]=1
test[269, 155]=1
test[269, 156]=1
test[269, 157]=1
test[270, 156]=1
```

I have the following ellipse:
[image: bad ellipse]

To get this result, you can just run the following code with python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
def getContours_test(clusters):
        copy_clusters=clusters.copy()
        int_cnts=[]
        for label in np.unique(clusters):
                mask = np.zeros(clusters.shape, dtype="uint8")
                mask[clusters == label] = 255
                cnts, hierarchy = \
                        cv2.findContours(mask.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
                int_cnts.append(cnts)
        list_contours=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(int_cnts))
        return copy_clusters, list_contours


def getEllipse_test(clusters, list_contours):
        for index,cnt in enumerate(list_contours):
                map_ellipse=np.ones(clusters.shape).astype(np.uint8)
                cimg = np.zeros_like(clusters)
                cv2.drawContours(cimg, list_contours, index, color=255, thickness=-1)
                ellipse=cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
                cv2.ellipse(map_ellipse,ellipse,(255,0,0))
        return map_ellipse

test_result, test_contours = getContours_test(test)
test_ellipse = getEllipse_test(test_result,test_contours)
mpl.contourf(test_result)
mpl.contour(test_ellipse)
mpl.show()
```

I tried to see if I could reproduce the same behavior with a similar but simpler form (new form is filled while original is contoured):
[image: 2 forms]
but this time, I get a correct result with the same code
[image: good ellipse]

```
test2=np.zeros((400,1000))
test2[240:260,110:120]=1
test2[260:265,117:134]=1
test2[265:270,134:155]=1
test_result2, test_contours2 = getContours_test(test2)
test_ellipse2 = getEllipse_test(test_result2,test_contours2)
mpl.contourf(test_result2)
mpl.contour(test_ellipse2)
mpl.show()
```

Any idea why this is happening? cv2.fitEllipse should have enough contour points to estimate the correct ellipse of the original form.

EDIT: 
Following the remark from @user2518618, I tried to include cv2.convexHull() in a method:

```
def remove_convex(clusters,list_contours):
        for index,cnt in enumerate(list_contours):
                map_ellipse=np.ones(clusters.shape).astype(np.uint8)
                cimg = np.zeros_like(clusters)
                hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
                cv2.drawContours(cimg, hull, -1, color=255, thickness=-1)
        return cimg
```

resulting a selection of points suitable for an ellipse to be estimated:

```
test_hull = remove_convex(test_result,test_contours)

mpl.contour(test_hull)
mpl.show()
```

[image: points remaining after cv2.convexHull()]

But if I add `ellipse=cv2.fitEllipse(hull)` after `hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)` in remove_convex, I get the following error:
error: (-201) Number of points should be >= 5 in function cvFitEllipse2

Although I understand the error since the opencv documentation says that convex hull returns the four corners of a rectangle, I don't really understand why I just can't use the points plotted above to fit my new ellipse.

Comment: "I couldn't find a better way to describe the 2D array" -- 2D array of small integers, using a computer vision library... how about a grayscale image? (the resulting PNG is about 7x smaller than the code you used to generate it)

Answer (score 0):

fitEllipse() would work much better if your shape looked like an ellipse.

Your shape is very noisy and it is difficult to find an ellipse that fits it properly. Actually, both ellipses that the algorithm found pass near the points of your shape and both may be good approximations.

You should preprocess your shape to make it look more like an ellipse. I would try using cv2.convexHull() before fitEllipse()

Comment: That's a good idea indeed. However, cv2.convexHull() returns only 4 points (cf. opencv doc.) while I need at least 5 points to be able to fit an ellipse. `hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)` and `ellipse=cv2.fitEllipse(hull)` gives: `error: (-201) Number of points should be >= 5 in function cvFitEllipse2`