# Using cv2.FitEllipse to fit ellipse to thinned binary image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to detect a pot hole in an image of a road surface using python. I have managed to get from an image to a thinned binary image. I now want to circle the pothole using the thinned image I have. I have tried using cv2.FitEllipse and not had any success because I do not think I am using the function correctly.
[seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQcMr.png)

[Binary Thinned Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul8ME.png)

Once circled on the image I would also like to find the pixel area and centre of the ellipse.

Would anyone know how to fit an ellipse to that binary thinned image?

Comment: "I have tried using cv2.FitEllipse and not had any success because I do not think I am using the function correctly." Please show that code, so we can point out what is wrong with it. Also describe what "not any success" means: did you get an error message, wrong output, no output, ...? Please be specific and show exactly what you see.

Comment: I am not familiar with the fucntion so tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918522/ellipse-fitting-for-images-using-fitellipse) 
 but when I tried using that exact code on an example image like the above I got the error 'There should be at least 5 points to fit the ellipse in function' I then tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162657/why-does-cv2-fitellipse-considers-contours-as-side-of-ellipse) but what not sure how to apply that code to my situation

Comment: There is no unique circle to which to fit

Comment: I thought FitEllipse could be used to fit an ellipse to a set of points which are not a complete ellipse using least squares ellipse fitting

Comment: @CrisLuengo I after getting that error message above I was getting no output.

Comment: @fmw42 do you mean that the function will try and fit a small circle to the thinned image as it is not one strand?

Comment: `@Tom` Yes, not one strand and perhaps not full enough ellipses either. It will do a fit, but perhaps not very well

Comment: @fmw42 how would you go about removing the extra strands? - I found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481596/python-image-finding-largest-branch-from-image-skeleton) however it did highlighted a path that kept the circular strands in it.

Comment: @Tom. What result do you get if you fit and ellipse to the existing data? If that is semi-reasonable, you could try iterating and throwing out the pixels furthest from the ellipse. Then fit the ellipse again. Stop when you only have pixels within some threshold distance.

Comment: Currently I am running:
 
'cnts, hiers = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]

for cnt in cnts:
    ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
    cv2.ellipse(img, ellipse, (255,0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

viewer4 = skimage.viewer.ImageViewer(img)
viewer4.show(block)' 

 and getting the error message:

 error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function 'cvStartFindContours_Impl'

Comment: @fmw42 any ideas on the above?